# How to display image from known image path - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've got an array of image URLs (all from storage, not internet). How can I show the images themselves?
Simplified code:

```
@Binding var files:[URL]//Array of image URLs taken from an NSOpenPanel instance

Form{
    if files.count>0{
        Image(files[0].path)//Problem
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say `NSOpenPanel`, so I'm making going to make the assumption here that we don't need to worry about waiting to load the image over a network:

```
if let nsImage = NSImage(contentsOf: url) {
  Image(nsImage: nsImage)
}
```